# Solr - how to use only the top boost value to rank the result?

Tags: solr, lucene, ranking, boosting, lucene-boosting

In a Solr query with boosting, I would like that solr uses only the top boost value to rank the result, ignoring the secondary score matches.

For example:

```
q=field_1=123^100 OR field_2=123^50 OR field_3=123^10
```

If one document match with two fields, I only want to be taken into account the one with the highest score in the ranking.

I only have found the `tie` parameter, but I don't want to use DisMax parser.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Max Score Query Parser

```
{!maxscore tie=0.0}( ... )
```